# Get the width/height of the JSFiddle result window while in <head>

Tags: javascript, html, onload, jsfiddle

Is it possible to get the dimensions of the JSFiddle 'result' window, using only vanilla javascript, while in `<head>` or `<body>` (referring to the drop down menu on the left)?

Inspecting the HTML, this is the object I'm trying to get dimensions of:

```
<div id="result" class="window bottom">...</div>
```

Here is a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/27gye/2/) of what I'm trying to do. Is what I'm asking even possible?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/27gye/1/

Comment: Your script is executed in the document that is loaded in iframe (which has the id `result`)  thats why your code can't find that element.

Comment: You can't access the javascript methods outside of an iframe